# MySQL - How is the row size above 65535

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, limit, rows

I understand that the maximum row limit in mysql is 65535, which is equal to `(2 ^ 16) - 1`. I also understand that it is bad database design to have extremely long rows like that. However, this is my schema

```
CREATE TABLE mytable(
  a VARCHAR(20000),
  b VARCHAR(20000),
  c VARCHAR(20000),
  d VARCHAR(5535)
) CHARACTER SET=latin1;
```

This is the output I get

> Row size too large. The maximum row size for the used table type, not counting BLOBs, is **65535**. This includes storage overhead, check the manual. You have to change some columns to TEXT or BLOBs

Let's do the math again

```
20000 + 20000 + 20000 + 5535 = 65535
```

which is equal to and does not surpass the limit. For the record, the highest value for column d that works is `5526`.

I do not understand where those additional 9 characters come from.

Comment: Where is the length of the strings stored in your calculation?…

Comment: In your case, there's two bytes each for variable length column over 255 bytes in length. That's eight bytes. Plus an additional byte to hold the NULL indicators for all four of the columns. A total of nine bytes. (That explains why the size of that last column caps out at 5526.)

Comment: Yep, the more columns you create the fewer characters you are allowed. I tested more columns, and the limits decreased by 2 each time.

Comment: The overhead and maximum row size will vary with the storage engine used for the table. Most common storage engines are MyISAM and InnoDB, and both of those engines have a variety of ROW_FORMAT options.

Comment: Would you like to explain why you have fields like that?  There may be a workaround that achieves the _real_ goal.

Comment: This is not my database and I already admitted it's bad database design. I just knew what the MySQL table limits were, but didn't understand why an example surpassed these limits

Comment: Which is kind of surprising anyway. Single columns in postgres can be over 100 times bigger than an entire row in mysql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The size of VARCHAR is calculated like this:

**len + 1 bytes if column is 0 – 255 bytes, len + 2 bytes if column may require more than 255 bytes**

so

```
CREATE TABLE mytable(
  a VARCHAR(20000),       -- 20002
  b VARCHAR(20000),       -- 20002
  c VARCHAR(20000),       -- 20002
  d VARCHAR(5535)         --  5537
) CHARACTER SET=latin1;--    65543 !!!! 8 Bytes to much
```

see this https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/data-type-storage-requirements/

Comment: Then why doesn't `d VARCHAR(5527)` work? The sum is 65535 which equals the limit. Where does that extra character come from?

Comment: Try this to see where the Storage Engine use Space: CREATE TABLE mytable(
  a VARCHAR(20000) NOT NULL,
  b VARCHAR(20000) NOT NULL,
  c VARCHAR(20000) NOT NULL,
  d VARCHAR(5527)  NOT NULL
) CHARACTER SET=latin1;

Comment: Now I understand. That extra character comes from not having a `NOT NULL` constraint on one or more columns.

Comment: Im have not read the Documentation, but i am nearly sure that the Engine use one bit for each NULL. SO you can use 8 Fields with NULL to reduce the size by 1

Comment: Is this true for `INNODB` only or for all engines?

Comment: Every Engine can handle this in his own wise. You also can program your own engine to store the data in every type or length.

Answer (score 2):

from: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/column-count-limit.html

```
         row length = 1
         + (sum of column lengths)
         + (number of NULL columns + delete_flag + 7)/8
         + (number of variable-length columns)
```

Try change column type to VARCHAR (20000) NOT NULL

Comment: yep, that accounts for one of the characters. If that constraint is added to all columns, you get one extra character